# В чем разница в создании потоков используя Thread и Runnable?

Tags: java, многопоточность

А если быть конкретнее - интересует вот что.
Допустим у нас есть код, вот такой:

```
public class Main{  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(myThread);
        t1.start();
        myThread.sysOut();  
    }
}

public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
    }

    public void sysOut(){
        System.out.println("Banana!");
    }
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что вызывая `myThread.sysOut()` этот метод будет вызываться в основном потоке, а не в потоке `t1` ?
Если же я понимаю правильно, каким образом извне вызвать метод `sysOut` не в основном потоке имплементируя интерфейс `Runnable`, а не наследуясь от класса `Thread` ?

Comment: Не реализуя его в классе потока. Класс потока вообще не стоит наследовать без причины.

Comment: Правильно. sysOut будет выполнен в основном потоке. t1, являясь типичным представителем своего класса Thread, в своём потоке выполняет метод run() класса, реализующего Runnable. Thread создан запускать Runnable.run. Runnable создан, чтобы Thread запускал его метод run, Только так. Таким образом вопрос не корректный. Thread и Runnable не сравнимы между собой. Они созданы для совместной работы.

Comment: А в случае с наследованием Thread любой вызываемый на объекте метод будет в новом потоке, верно ?

Comment: Нет. В новом потоке будет только то что выполняется в потоке. т.е. метод от класса не зависит, зависит от того где вызвать.

Comment: Хотите вызывать методы в другом потоке? Изучайте взаимодействие потоков: синхронизацию, блокировки, очереди, диспетчеры всякие. Поток не может ничего вызывать в другом потоке. Но может послать какой-нибудь условный сигнал, по которому другой поток поймёт, что нужно сделать.

Answer (score 4):

Нельзя прямо вот так взять и вызвать метод в другом потоке.
Можно каким-то образом послать в поток условный сигнал, по которому он поймёт что от него требуется и сделает это.

```
public class Main{  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(myThread);
        t1.start();
        myThread.sysOutInThread();  
    }
}

public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
        synchronized (this) {
            wait(); // ждать сигнал
        }
        sysOut();
    }

    public void sysOut(){
        System.out.println("Banana!");
    }

    public void sysOutInThread() {
        synchronized (this) {
            notifyAll();  // просигнализировать
        }
    }

}
```

Основной поток -> `t1.start()` -> `myThread.run()` -> `myThread.wait()`
`run()` уже выполняется в новом потоке t1
Поток t1 "зависает" в `wait()`

Основной поток -> `myThread.sysOutInThread()` -> `myThread.notifyAll()`
Выполняется всё в основном потоке.
`notifyAll()` посылает сигнал ожидающему потоку t1

`wait()` в потоке t1 получает сигнал и поток выходит наконец-то из `wait()` и сразу же принимается выполнять `sysOut()`.
Всё выполняется в потоке t1.

На этом работа потока t1 прекращается. Можно зациклить `run()`, тогда опять будет ждать сигнал, по которому опять сделает `sysOut()` и так до бесконечности.

Answer (score 3):

Главное отличие, как по мне, это то, что `Runnable` - это интерфейс. От `Thread` же можно только наследоваться.

При использовании `Runnable` унаследоваться вы можете от другого класса.

Плюс с `Runnable` вы можете использовать `ThreadPoolExecutor`, передавая туда объект своего класса, реализующий `Runnable`.

Если есть возможность, лучше всегда использовать интерфейсы.

Comment: `Thread` реализует `Runnable`, так что его экземпляры тоже можно закидывать в экзекуторы, ну если вдруг легаси-код, или странного хочется.

Comment: Говорят что интерфейсы придумали из-за ущербности java - нет множественного наследия. И тогда получается ими вовсе и не лучше пользоваться, а потому, что больше нечем:)

Comment: @banme множественное наследование - пережиток C++. В нормальных системах никто никогда в здравом уме не будет использовать множественное наследование.

Comment: А ещё говорят в java 8 у интерфейсов появилась какая-то реализация по умолчанию. Интересно, она наследуется? Тогда получается  какое-то подобие наследие множественного наследия, которое как совсем недавно выяснилось было пережитком, но вот теперь вроде как инновация

Comment: @banme мне кажется, вы не понимаете, о чём говорите)

Answer (score 2):

**Thread** - это собственно сам поток который что то выполняет

**Runnable** - это интерфейс, который *съедает* поток чтобы что-то выполнить

т.е. Thread стремится уйти в парралель и что-то там сделать. Что-то сделать - означает вызвать метод run у переданного ему при создании Runnable объекта.